# ORA-00904: " ": invalid identifier for identifying space in instr

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using

```
substr( item_name, instr(item_name," ",1,1)-1 )
```

to get the name of an item before space.

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Besides the obvious (in Oracle you should use single quotes for string literals), the formula you wrote won't do what you want. It should be substr( item_name, 1, instr(....) ) -  the second argument tells you where to start reading from (in this case, from the first character), and only the third argument - the instr() - tells you HOW MUCH to read.

Answer (score 2):

Try using single quote

```
 substr( item_name, instr(item_name, ' ' ,1,1)-1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the string character, which should be a single quote.

This is often handled using `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(item_name, '^([^ ]*)[ ]', 1, 1)
```

Comment: Always best to use "standard" instr and substr unless the code becomes too complicated. In this case that solution is easier to read AND more efficient than the regexp solution.

Comment: @mathguy . . . That is one way to look at it.  I look at it another way.  There's a good chance that the next thing someone will want is the second word.